# $c(t)$ geodesic $\Rightarrow$ $c(\alpha t)$ geodesic.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, surfaces, parametrization, geodesic

Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular surface with Riemannian metric $g$.

Moreover let $p\in S$, $v\in T_pS$ and $c$ a geodesic with $c(0)=p$ and $c'(0)=v$.

I want to show that for any constant $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ the curve $c_\alpha(t):=c(\alpha t)$ is also a geodesic with respect to the boundary conditions $c_\alpha(0)=p$ and $c_\alpha'(0)=\alpha v$.

My attempt is to verify that the energy functionals are the same.

But why is

$$E[c_\alpha]=\frac{1}{2}\int_Ig_{c_\alpha(t)}(c'_\alpha(t),c'_\alpha(t))dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_I\alpha^2g_{c(\alpha t)}(c'(\alpha t),c'(\alpha t))dt$$

the same as

$$E[c]=\frac{1}{2}\int_I g_{c(t)}(c'(t),c'(t))dt\quad\text{?}$$

I tried to use integration by substitution, but this would change the integration interval $I$.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: The energy functionals are not the same, consider the curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to [0,1]$, $t\mapsto t$ which is a geodesic in $\Bbb R$. Then $\int_0^1 |\gamma'(t)|^2 \,dt = \frac13$ whereas if you rescale $\gamma_a$ you get $\int_0^{1/a}(at)^2\,dt = \frac1{3a}$. What is the same is the path length.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! How can I show that it is a geodesic then? I thought a geodesic is a minimum of the energy functional.

Comment: Its a minimum for different boundary conditions.

Comment: Well, is it right, if $c$ is a geodesic it holds, that it is parameterized by arclength and $2(b-a)E[c]=L[c]^2$, if $I=[a,b]$? So I have to consider $c_\alpha$ on another intervall?

Comment: If the geodesic is parametrised by arclength then $E[c]=1/2 L[c]$, because then $g(c', c')=1$.

Comment: Yes, but then $L[c]=\int_a^bdt=b-a$ for $I=[a,b]$, right?

Comment: Yes, taht is correct

Comment: I have to show, that $E[c_\alpha]2(b-a)=L[c_\alpha]^2$?

Comment: No that isnt true, in order to check that $c_a$ is a minimum wrt boundary condition $c_a'(0)= av$ and $c_a(0)=p$ try writing out the Euler Lagrange equations of the energy, and see how they change under rescaling of the argument of $c$.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Actually chekc that $E[c_a]= \frac1{|a|} E[c]$. You can leverage this to get the result.